# Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG's state extra always returns on 1

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I'm using BroadcastReceiver in order to know if headphones are plugged to the device, but the "status" intent extra immediately returns on 1 (plugged) in every case.

Here is my code:

```
public class Class {

  boolean isHeadsetOn;
  IntentFilter headsetReceiverFilter;
  HeadsetPluggedReceiver headsetReceiver;

  public Class(Context context) {
    this.headsetReceiverFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
    this.headsetReceiver = new HeadsetPluggedReceiver();
    context.registerReceiver(this.headsetReceiver, this.headsetReceiverFilter);
  }

  private class HeadsetPluggedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      switch(intent.getIntExtra("state", -1)) {
        case 0:
          Synthesizer.this.isHeadsetOn = false;
          Log.d("onreceive", "off");
        case 1:
          Synthesizer.this.isHeadsetOn = true;
          Log.d("onreceive", "on");
        default:
          // shit
      }
    }

  }

}
```

This is my log:

```
// not plugged. plugging in
onreceive | on
// unplugging
onreceive | off
onreceive | on
// plugging in again
onreceive | on
// plugging off again
onreceive | off
onreceive | on
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need break statements in your switch case. Right now your logic is falling through to case 1.

Answer (score 1):

**should be : **

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  switch(intent.getIntExtra("state", -1)) {
    case 0:
      Synthesizer.this.isHeadsetOn = false;
      Log.d("onreceive", "off");
      break; //<---------
    case 1:
      Synthesizer.this.isHeadsetOn = true;
      Log.d("onreceive", "on");
      break; //<---------
    default:
      // shit
  }
}

}
```